# Having issues getting rb.fit() to work for a sentiment analysis project. Python 3.9.12

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Getting back into coding after a while of being away.

I'm having issues getting rb.fit() to work for a sentiment analysis project. Python 3.9.12 Also open to other recommendations if you think RandomBaseline is just no good.

```
rb = RandomBaseline()
#rb.fit(data, target_col)
rb.fit(df_text_analysis, df_text_analysis['Q6'])
```

I found the code https://asperbrothers.com/blog/sentiment-analysis-in-python/ and it seems I have it setup the same way but I'm getting a KeyError: nan

```
rb = RandomBaseline()
rb.fit(df.iloc[X_train.index], "Sentiment")
```

Error output below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3621, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620 try:
-> 3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: nan

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [12], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 rb = RandomBaseline()
      2 #rb.fit(data, target_col)
----> 3 rb.fit(df_text_analysis, df_text_analysis['Q6'])

Input In [11], in RandomBaseline.fit(self, data, target_col)
      9 agg = data.groupby(target_col).count()
     11 for n in feels:
---> 12     self.categories[n] = agg.loc[n][0] / len(data)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:967, in _LocationIndexer.__getitem__(self, key)
    964 axis = self.axis or 0
    966 maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
--> 967 return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1202, in _LocIndexer._getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1200 # fall thru to straight lookup
   1201 self._validate_key(key, axis)
-> 1202 return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1153, in _LocIndexer._get_label(self, label, axis)
   1151 def _get_label(self, label, axis: int):
   1152     # GH#5667 this will fail if the label is not present in the axis.
-> 1153     return self.obj.xs(label, axis=axis)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:3864, in NDFrame.xs(self, key, axis, level, drop_level)
   3862             new_index = index[loc]
   3863 else:
-> 3864     loc = index.get_loc(key)
   3866     if isinstance(loc, np.ndarray):
   3867         if loc.dtype == np.bool_:

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3623, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:
-> 3623     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3624 except TypeError:
   3625     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3626     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3627     #  the TypeError.
   3628     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: nan
```

Comment: Have you done the previous part where they set `df["Sentiment"]` to a string value?

Comment: I don't see where they set to a string, but that might make sense. Giving that a go!

Comment: After that, have you done the next part where they use `train_test_split()` to split the data? Because that's where the values for `fit()` comes from

Comment: Yep. I've done the `train_test_split()` and all seemed to work there.